laravel -> file_put_contents(/var/www/laravel/storage/framework/views/9f1dc9629406f3376fc417dd6985a806.php): Failed to open stream: Permission denied
docker-compose.yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  nginx:
    image: "nginx:stable-alpine"
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql
  php:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    ports:
      - "3316:3306"
    env_file:
      - ./env/mysql.env
  composer:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: composer.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel
  artisan:
    build:
      context: dockerfiles
      dockerfile: php.Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/laravel
    entrypoint: ["php", "/var/www/laravel/artisan"]

php.Dockerfile
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/laravel

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}

Error
enter image description here
in the php.dockerfile file I tried to add a line to change access
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/laravel

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/storage          /*    <------  new line   */

I also tried to change access to the storage folder through WSL
@DESKTOP-VIGTBDU:/src/storage$ sudo chmod -R 777 .


I think storage/framework and storage/framework/views would also need to have their permissions updated..? But you aren't really asking a question, merely posting a wall of code and expecting a solution to your undescribed problem.

You have mounted ./src:/var/www/laravel. At that point, no changes you make to the image for the /var/www/laravel directory matter, the container will have the files, ownership, and permission, of the files on the volume. You need to remove the volume mount or fix the access in your directories on the host (./src directory).

Most likely, you transferred your project or loaded it from a repository. The issue is not with the folder itself but with the rendered cache file. You need to clear all the cache. Start by trying php artisan optimize & php artisan view:clear (view:clear might be sufficient on its own). This will delete those files, and on the next application initialization, the framework will create new files with the correct permissions.
